# Customized Windows XP installation

Tags: windows-xp, installation

How to create a customized version of an Windows XP installation CD?

I want a hand's off installation that will install all the themes, drivers, and applications I need without my intervention. How can I do that?

I tried to make use of this software called [nLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NLite_and_vLite). But then I tested the ISO file using [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox). The VirtualBox said that there's a certain file that cannot be copied. And by the way, before I customized the original ISO image of Windows XP SP3, it doesn't have the file copying problem that I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 'no one-fits-all' solution to Windows customization.

If you're new to nLite, look around and you will find plenty ready-made nLite presets (AKA **session.ini** files) on the interwebs.

Answer (score 1):

nLite IS the software to do it. Anything else isn't as good - nLite is the standard for a reason. It's not infallible, but do try again.